# quicksort string array help c++

Tags: c++, string, quicksort

This is my code. I don't know how to get the code to run. Im having problems with quicksorting for string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>



using namespace std;

int count;
template <class T>
void printArray(T ar[], int sz);
template <class T>
void bubbleSort(T ar[], int sz);
void quickSortMain(string items[], int ct);
void quickSort(string items[], int left, int right);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main Function Implementation
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() {
    int numOfData = 50000;
    string line, temp;
    ofstream resultFile;
    ofstream tableFile;
    double data[100][2];
    string patient[numOfData];
    ifstream dataFile("shufflePatient.txt");
    int i;
    int SIZE = 0;

    cout << "Program to shuffle data" << endl << endl;
    cout << "This program will calculate swapping processes and running time.";


    /*Storing data*/
    cout << "Reading data in process.." << endl;
    if (dataFile.is_open()) {
        i=-1;
        while (dataFile.good()) {
            getline (dataFile, line);
            if (i>=0) patient[i] = line;
            i++;
        }
        dataFile.close();
    }

    SIZE = 5;
    quickSortMain(patient, 5);


    /*Writing to file*/
    cout << "Writing to file.." << endl;
    resultFile.open ("test.txt");
    for (int i=0 ; i<numOfData ; i++) {
        resultFile << patient[i] << "\n";
    }
    resultFile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


void quickSortMain(string items[], int ct)
{
  quickSort(items, 0, ct-1);
}


void quickSort(string items[], int left, int right)
{
  int i, j;
  char *x;
  string temp[10];

  i = left;
  j = right;
  x = items[(left+right)/2];

  do {
    while((strcmp(items[i],x) < 0) && (i < right)) {
       i++;
    }
    while((strcmp(items[j],x) > 0) && (j > left)) {
        j--;
    }
    if(i <= j) {
      strcpy(temp, items[i]);
      strcpy(items[i], items[j]);
      strcpy(items[j], temp);
      i++;
      j--;
   }
  } while(i <= j);

  if(left < j) {
     quickSort(items, left, j);
  }
  if(i < right) {
     quickSort(items, i, right);
  }
}









//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// prints array of size size
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
void printArray(T patient[], int size)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << patient[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
}




//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// sorts array of size size by Bubble Sort method
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
void bubbleSort(T patient[], int size) //returning an int
{
    bool noChange = true;
    for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
  {
    noChange = true;
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j++)
    {
      if(patient[j] < patient[j - 1])
      {
        swap(patient[j], patient[j-1]);
        count = count + 1;
        noChange = false;
      }
    }
    if (noChange)
      return ;
  }
}
```

The error i got was in this line:

```
 x = items[(left+right)/2];
```

I changed

`char x*;`  to `string x;`

I don't know if that was correct. Now the error im getting is that `strcmp` and `strcpy` are not declared. Any help on what i should do next?

Comment: VLAs are not standard.

Comment: Strings can be compared with `<` and `>` and assigned with `=`.  No need for `strcmp` and `strcpy`.

Comment: 1. Get rid of the `left` and `right`, You only need `len` if you're remotely proficient with pointer math. 2. Stop using C runtime functions for things provided for your by the C++ runtime, such as the `operator <` overload for `std::string`

Answer (score 2):

That's correct, now change

```
strcmp(items[i],x) < 0
```

to

```
items[i] < x
```

and

```
strcmp(items[j],x) > 0
```

to

```
items[j] > x
```

and

```
strcpy(temp, items[i]);
```

to

```
temp = items[i];
```

etc.

But really this is a case of RTFM. If you're competent enough to write a quicksort routine you should be competent enough to look up how `std::string` works. Being able to access reference information is a very important skill for a programmer.

Comment: Also change `string temp[10];` to `string temp;` although `std::swap` would be a better choice to swap items.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Right I missed that. I guess it used to be `char temp[10];`. `std::swap` is a better choice but I left it as is to show the equivalence of `strcpy` and `=`. Maybe the OP can practice his research skills by looking up `std::swap`.

Comment: thank you for all the comments!!
last question.
could you guys guide we as to where i should research std::string and std::swap from? most of the websites i open dont really explain both of these that much in regard with quicksort.

Comment: @user2959974 This one's OK http://en.cppreference.com/w/. Look up std::string and std::swap, but look them up for themselves, not just for quicksort.

Comment: @user2959974 Note: that website is **the** website for all things related to the C++ language and standard library. It is heads and tails better than anything else you will find online.